# PHP url issue and google maps

Tags: php, google-maps

I am trying to get google map populate with a mysql database and some php code.  I followed the following tutorial (http://www.macrostash.com/2011/09/17/demo-use-a-php-mysql-database-to-load-markers-on-a-google-map/) and everything works good.

My problem is I want to add a url to my google maps marker bubble.

The minute I add a href link the map just does not go.

Example:

```
    "<p class='content'><b>Park:</b>".$row[1]. <- Works
    "<p class='content'><b>Park:</b>".domain. <- Works
    "<p class='content'><b>Park:</b><a href=\" ".$domain." \">".$row[1]."</a>". <- No Luck
```

I only problem I can see is the first record seems to be prased wrong.

```
<input type="hidden" id="encodedString" name="encodedString" value="&lt;p class='content'&gt;&lt;b&gt;Park:&lt;/b&gt;Basinview School&lt;br&gt;&lt;b&gt;Park:&lt;/b&gt;&lt;**a href=" http:="" test.com="" "="">**
```

The slashes are missing just from the first record.

Any help would be grateful.

**EDIT**
This is the whole part I have.

```
 $encodedString = $encodedString.$separator.
  "<p class='content'><b>Park:</b><a href=\" ".$domain." \">".$row[1]."</a>".
  "<br><b>Address:</b> ".$row[2].
  "<br><b>Area: </b>".$row[3].
  "</p>&&&".$row[4]."&&&".$row[5];
```

Comment: You're not closing your `<p>` tags ...

Comment: what kind of values does row[1] contain?

Comment: What do you mean by "the map just does not go"? In any case, check the error console for javascript errors. Also I suggest you do `<a href=\"".$domain."\">` instead of `<a href=\" ".$domain." \">` (lose the spaces)

Answer (score 2):

You're not closing your `<p>` tags. If you go back to your tutorial you will see that they close them... You need to use this

```
"<p class='content'><b>Park:</b>".$row[1]."</p>
<p class='content'><b>Park:</b>".domain."</p>
<p class='content'><b>Park:</b><a href=\" ".$domain." \">".$row[1]."</a></p>"
```